# Adding media file attachment to wordpress post page error

Tags: wordpress

Every time when i upload media file in WordPress post page, there happens an error, any solution?

`An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change the file permission via FTP to 777.

Comment: This may be the answer to the question, in wordpress proper write permission need to be set to the folder which is 777